# Error message on running Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, server

I just started to use Eclipse for web development, so I'll try to do a connection from a web application to a Telegram group for automatic messages. I'm just starting in web dev and I can't run Apache Tomcat server. I'm receiving an error message, but I don't understand it. Anyone can help me please?

This is the message error:

```
jun 01, 2017 9:55:23 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
GRAVE: Begin event threw error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\nio.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x0) on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper.getBufferPoolMXBeans(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.PlatformComponent$11.getMXBeans(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.PlatformComponent.getMXBeans(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.getMBeanServer(Registry.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createServer(MBeanUtils.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.<clinit>(MBeanUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.<clinit>(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:117)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1204)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\nio.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x0) on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper.getBufferPoolMXBeans(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.PlatformComponent$11.getMXBeans(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.PlatformComponent.getMXBeans(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry.getMBeanServer(Registry.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createServer(MBeanUtils.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.<clinit>(MBeanUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.<clinit>(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:117)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1204)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
```

Comment: Which tomcat Version doo you use?

Comment: I solved. The problem was the version of my JRE. I was using a **default one (1.8.1_91)** and had to update to **latest version (1.8.1_131)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved. The problem was the version of my JRE. I was using a default one (1.8.1_91) and had to update to latest version (1.8.1_131)